# Adding View to LinqToSql Diagram Doesn't Create Methods/Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I'm using VS 2010 and LinqToSql. When I drag a view onto the diagram and set my relations, the XML is updated but the class does not get updated with the supporting methods and properties.

Before when I've done this, I would get a property like so:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Question_QuestionAggregatesView", Storage="_QuestionAggregatesView", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="Id", IsUnique=true, IsForeignKey=false)]
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order=38, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public QuestionAggregatesView QuestionAggregates
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.serializing 
                        && (this._QuestionAggregatesView.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return this._QuestionAggregatesView.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            QuestionAggregatesView previousValue = this._QuestionAggregatesView.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._QuestionAggregatesView.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._QuestionAggregatesView.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.Question = null;
                }
                this._QuestionAggregatesView.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.Question = this;
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("QuestionAggregates");
            }
        }
    }
```

But LinqToSql didn't create this type of property for my newly added view.

Is this a bug in VS2010 or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after some sophisticated search engine query manipulation:

http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/linq-to-sql-not-generating-code-for-association

Thanks Bart Lannoeye for your helpful post. In short, because I added a view to the diagram, a primary key wasn't added by default. I had to specify the primary key for the view in the diagram, and all worked fine after that.